# Storing a date as an integer in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to run some reports on a MySQL database created by a former employee. He has stored dates as integers. I have worked backwards and looked as some PDF reports previously generated. I know for sure that numeric ID 78496 is 27th November 2015 and 78514 is 15th December 2015

```
ordered = 78496 = 27/11/2015
required = 78514 = 15/12/2015
```

The IDs are 18 apart, this is also the number of days between Nov 27th and Dec 15th.

I have never come across this way of storing dates. Is anybody familiar with a function that I can call to convert these IDs into YYYY-MM-DD ?

edit. I have checked and 78486 is the number of days between Dec 28th 1800 and 27th Nov 2015

Comment: ô_U Seriously ? Date, string, timestamp, and he made a custom one from scratch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number seems to be the number of days from a starting date.

This is around 100 years behind 01/01/1900 as this is 42,335 days in the past.

Given the correct base date, just add the number of days and you're done.

In order to find the base date, just do it the other way round with the test dates.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2015-12-15', INTERVAL 78514 DAY);
```

BTW gives "1800-12-28" and

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2015-11-27', INTERVAL 78496 DAY);
```

exactly the same.

Some thoughts:

1800-12-28 looks weird and I assume that this has been 1900-01-01 and that there are flaws in the calculation of leap years, 1800 and 1900 and 2000 are not leap years due to the century-rule. Makes exactly the diff of three days ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a function that will convert the number you give to a sensible date. Use that for light-weight operations only though.

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create function SensibleDate(val int)
    -> returns date
    -> begin
    ->   return date_add(cast('1800-12-28' as date), interval val day);
    -> end; //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> select SensibleDate(78496);
+---------------------+
| SensibleDate(78496) |
+---------------------+
| 2015-11-27          |
+---------------------+
```

More important than just creating a function like this, it would be best if you can convince (if need be) decision-makers to replace that field with a new field that holds valid date values. To that table, add a new column that holds date data type. Then calculate date from the integers. Go through code and replace the use of integers to valid date field and then drop that column (after taking a backup).

Like the leap year caveat Alex describes, you'll have to do some thorough research on the dates and ensure you can replicate behaviors exhibited by the use of integer data type.